# Java regex insert single character between two patterns

Tags: java, regex

Let's say I have for example a string... 
`2*Math.sqrt(5265+Math.sin(53*2*Math.exp(3+(5+5)*3`
I'd like to get following string by using regex...
`2*Math.sqrt(5265)+Math.sin(53)*2*Math.exp(3)+(5+5)*3`

So if I am right I just need to insert `)` into a string, right between an unknown-length number [0-9] and a operator, which can be one of `* - / +`.

Furthermore, I'd like to know if (how?) it is possible to get an extended version supporting both `Math.pow` and above examples. At the moment, I'm using only single-argument `Math.*` methods, which are OK with above not-implemented-yet solution. But what if I'd like to use `Math.pow`?
 So let's just say, that input string is for example...
`2*Math.sqrt(5265+Math.sin(53*2*Math.exp(3+(5+5)*3*24Math.pow(3*5*Math.sin(5` 

And the output I wish looks like...
 `2*Math.sqrt(5265)+Math.sin(53)*2*Math.exp(3)+(5+5)*3*Math.pow(24,3)*5*Math.sin(5)`

*(I am asking, because then I'd like to pass edited strings to `ScriptEngine` `eval`.)*

**Edit**
Yes, sorry, I haven't made myself clear. I actually don't care whether I get `*2*` or `*(2)*` because ScriptEngine's method eval takes both and at the moment I can't imagine any problems with these forms. 
Second, I'd like to get general solution with every single operator `* - / +`, strings mentioned above were just examples. I'll try to be more specific. So now ignoring the second `Math.pow` part, the main string, let's call it `A`, basically consists of one or more strings in the form that looks like this...
 `QWMath.[a-z](XWY`, where `Q` is `[0-9]`, `W` is one of `* - / +` and `X` is again `[0-9]`.
`QW` and `Y` are both optional, where `Y` is either another `A` string or `[0-9]`, which is connected to the previous string with a `W` operator.

 
But it seems, that femtoRgon's solution replacing `(Math\.[a-z]+\(\d+)` with `$1)` is OK.
For the Math.pow part: The femtoRgon's solution replacing `(\d+)(Math.pow\()(\d+)` with `$2$1$3)` is fine too except missing `,` in `$2$1$3)`. It should be `$2$1,$3)` and second, with `replace` method I had to add aditional backslashes: `(\\d+)(Math.pow\\()(\\d+)`, same with
 `(Math\.[a-z]+\(\d+)`...

So in the end I it seems It's quite sufficient to do something like this...

```
       String evalString = "2*Math.sqrt(5265+Math.sin(53*2*Math.exp(3+(5+5)*3*2554Math.pow(451";
       String firstPattern = "(\\d+)(Math.pow\\()(\\d+)";
       String secondPattern = "(Math\\.[a-z]+\\(\\d+)";

       String tempString = evalString.replaceAll(firstPattern, "$2$1,$3)");
       System.out.println(tempString.replaceAll(secondPattern, "$1"));
```

...maybe it can be much shorter. Of course it's not the exact solution, but the rest is just a cosmetic detail now.

Comment: What is the form of your input?  You don't explain why you want to insert `)` before some operators but not others, for example, the second asterisk in `*2*`.

Comment: Where is the 24 for the Math.pow() arg in the last output line supposed to come from?  Should all "pow(<number>" get converted to "pow(24,<number>)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your explanation, your first case sounds simple enough.  Simply replace:

```
(\(\d*)
```

with

```
$1)
```

However, this will not produce your desired output, but insteead will give you:

```
2*Math.sqrt(5265)+Math.sin(53)*2*Math.exp(3)+(5)+5)*3
```

What is the logic that would prevent you transforming `(5+5)` in that way?

Perhaps you only want to perform this with function begining with `Math.`?  In that case, you could try replacing:

```
 (Math\.[a-z]+\(\d+)
```

with

```
$1)
```

Don't run it twice though.  There is nothing stopping this from changing `Math.pow(3)` into `Math.pow(3))`

To transform `24Math.pow(3` in `Math.pow(24,3)`, you could replace:

```
(\d+)(Math.pow\()(\d+)
```

with

```
$2$1$3)
```